# How do I configure the <Super>D keybinding in Xfce to show desktop?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xfce

How can I  get the  <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> key binding in Xfce desktop? The <kbd>Start</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> is not working and invoking the Whisker menu but not showing the desktop. I tried changing, in the shortcuts, from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to <kbd>Start</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> but that still doesn't work.

This works well in Cinnamon when the <kbd>Super</kbd> key is pressed, the menu appears, and for <kbd>Start</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> it just works like in Windows.

What could be the reason, if it works in Cinnamon, it couldn't also work in Xfce?

Comment: Can you please explain how you tried changing the shortcuts?

Answer (score 13):

You can change the shortcuts that handle the window manager by opening Window Manager from Settings > Window Manager, Keyboard tab.

- Scroll down until you see Show desktop, (default
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
- Click to select the row, and press <kbd>Edit</kbd>
  [image: Window Manager]
- Press the desired keyboard keys combination on Window Manager Action Shortcut popup window (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in your case).
  [image: Window Manager Action Shortcut]
- Click <kbd>Close</kbd>.

This way Show desktop will be triggered by <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have the Super key bound to open the whisker menu, it seems

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**
Just take a look at the pictures below.

For cute sloths like myself, here goes a much longer explanation.
It's 2021 now and I've just encountered this very same issue.
I've tried all the variants suggested here in all the answers and comments posted here before mine and nothing helped me (including editing the XML config file and restarting X and PC after that). But I've noticed one thing in the user12458's answer. It's called xfconf. So I went to https://docs.xfce.org/ (which is hard not to notice on Google's search result page) and I saw these three things there:

- Configuration Storage System (**xfconf**) – D-Bus-based configuration storage system
- Settings Manager (**xfce4-settings**) – The Settings daemon which persists many Xfce settings
- Settings Editor – Editor that allows to modify all the various setting channels (**xfce4-settings-editor**)

You can open Settings Editor by typing **xfce4-settings-editor** in a terminal or as simple as it's shown on the picture below (it's the last one on the list):
[image]

To add Super-D shortcut for the Xfce window manager, you need to choose **xfce4-keyboard-shortcut** channel in the left pane, then scroll down the right pane till you see the **xfwm4** property and the **custom** property below it. Left-click on any item below **custom** and then click **New** button in the bottom part of the Settings Editor window. Take a look at another picture here:
[image]

In the Property box append `<Super>d` to the string `/xfwm4/custom/` that will be already there. Choose `String` for the `Type` box and write (or copy-paste from here) `show_desktop_key` to the `Value` box. Press **Save** button. The property editing dialog box should disappear now and your shortcut should be activated immediately after.

Comment: Thanks man, that really helped! :)

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem in Linux Mint 18 Xfce.

I've solved it with the solution in the answers of this link:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-show-desktop-in-xfce4-601161-print/

A script using the command «wmctrl -k on» and «wmctrl -k off»

```
#!/bin/sh
if xprop -root  _NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP|egrep '= 1' ; then
      wmctrl -k off ;
    else
      wmctrl -k on ;
    fi
```

You can create a shortcut to the script in the keyboard settings.

Comment: Didn't it conflict with Whisker menu? This happens if you have <Super> to trigger the whisker menu.

Comment: That's not a conflict for me if I have enough time <super>pulsed.  So I pulse first <Super> and then <D>  and I have no problem. In fact, I have more shortcuts with <super> + <letter>.  Also, if you want, you can delete de shortcut to Whisker menu in the keyboard settings.

Comment: Can that time be adjusted?

Comment: That the only solution worked from me `xubuntu` I add that script to new file `sudo nano /usr/local/sbin/showdesktop` and `sudo chmod +x showdesktop` Assatinate the shortcut from xfce setting / keyboard application shortcut menu

Answer (score 0):

To enable do this:

- Go to the folder `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/` (notice, this is a hidden folder, so, if you use Thunar, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to see hidden folders and files)
- Open the file `xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` **with a text editor** (if you double-click, it will open in a browser)
- Add the following line:

  ```
  <property name="&lt;Super&gt;d" type="string" value="show_desktop_key"/>
  ```

In my case I have it in the second subsection, `<property name="xfwm4" type="empty">`, but it might work in the first one, `<property name="commands" type="empty">`.

Comment: Not working for me!

Comment: Then try the above in the same file but in any of these folders (requires `sudo` power): `/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/` and `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/`

Comment: Not working still! Do I have to place it in defaults property? or just directly under xfmw4? I also tried logging out and testing! but still didn't work

Comment: Strange... have you tried modifying through the Settings Menu? Open the Settings (`xfce4-settings-manager` in the terminal), select Window Manager, then select Keyboard tab, and scroll down until you see "Show Desktop". Change that one using your key option.

Comment: Yes, but that didn't work.

Comment: That is **very** weird. They do work for me. I've just confirmed it by altering the bind. Which Ubuntu version are you running? Also, try using another bind (Alt+D for example). Are you sure you are using `Super` and not `Start`?

Comment: Alt+D worked fine for me. Yes, I am using Super key (when I edit it in the keyboard shortcuts, Super+D is only displayed). But on my keyboard it is labelled Start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43537/discussion-between-luchonacho-and-javatechnical).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in XFCE. If I go to Settings > Window Manager > Keyboard and assign the shortcut Super + D it works until the next restart. In order for this shortcut to work always, you need to first **remove** the existing shortcut assignment. So, first hit the button [Clear] to remove the default shortcut and then hit the Super + D combination. Otherwise, the existing shortcut remains "under cover" and interferes.

Also, of course, you may want to clear any other places where the Windows Key (Super) is used, e.g. to show Whisker Menu, because, otherwise every time you hit Super + D it will try to open Whisker Menu. For example, I use other combinations with the Windows Key, like Super + T = launch Terminal, Super + E = launch Thunar (analogy of Super + E on Windows, where it launches Windows Explorer). So, I had to clear the assignment of the Win Key to show Whisker Menu to prevent the menu from always popping up.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue seems to be the fact that Xfce triggers shortcuts bound to the `Super` key immediately when it is pressed down, not after it was released, making it impossible to trigger any other shortcut involving the `Super` key as long as there is a shortcut configured for the `Super` Key on its own.

It is possible to use `xcape` to remap keybindings on X11 to work around this issue. Xubuntu 22.04 should do this by default as it appears. (The `xubuntu-default-settings` package contains an autostart file called `xcape-super-binding.desktop` [[source](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/xubuntu-default-settings/filelist)])

If you are on an older version of Ubuntu or another distribution entirely this is how to set it up:
[Edit: Turns out there's also an [entry in the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xfce#Using_the_Windows_(Super)_key_for_shortcuts) about this, of course.]

- Install `xcape`
  `sudo apt install xcape`
- Create an autostart entry for `xcape -e 'Super_L=Alt_L|F1;Super_R=Alt_L|F1'`
  This simulates pressing `Alt+F1` when any of the `Super` keys is pressed and released on its own. You can of course customize this to whatever unused shortcut you want.
  You can create the entry in
  GUI using "Session and Startup" > "Application Autostart" > "Add"
  Alternatively, create the autostart file manually:

  - Open `~/.config/autostart/xcape-super-binding.desktop` in a text editor
  - Paste this text and save:

```ini
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Xfce xcape Super key workaround
Comment=Simulate Alt+F1 when the Super Key is pressed so it can still be used in other shortcuts.
Exec=xcape -e 'Super_L=Alt_L|F1;Super_R=Alt_L|F1'
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
```

- Log out and back in. If you open your system monitor there should be an entry for the xcape process running in the background. If not, make sure that the autostart entry is recognized properly and enabled in "Session and Startup" > "Application Autostart"
- Reconfigure the Shortcut for the Whiskermenu. It should then be set to `Alt+F1`

That's it. Keyboard shortcuts involving the `Super` key should now work in Xfce while the Whiskermenu still pops up when pressing the `Super` key on its own.